# Game of Life in React/Redux, help in increasing performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a  version of The Game of Life in react/redux/javascript, whilst i have it working the performance is horrible.

[Here is a link to the running game](https://dcc-game-of-life.herokuapp.com)
[Here's the source on githhub](https://github.com/gazzer82/fcc-game-of-life)

At the moment, i am at every tick (250,500,750ms changeable by the user) updating the state of each cell. For that i am looping through an array of objects that represent each cell. Within each object is a parameter called status which can be an integer on 1 for alive or 0 for dead.

I am then pulling in three rows of three cells, for the above middle and bottom rows around the cell in question, i then sum those values (excluding the cell itself in the centre).

I then run that number through an if/then flow to decide the new state of that cell.

This process then repeats for every single cell in the application. Once it's done the new state of each cell is dispatched using redux and the components update as needed.

In the actual view, each cell is a react component that receives it's state as a prop from the container which is the grid. I have setup shoulComponentRender() to only re-render the cell when it's life status changes.

I think from profiling the app (which i'm not very clear/good at) that it is the process of calculating all the values that is slowing things down, but i could be wrong and it could be the React components that are causing the issue.

Any help/assistance appreciated!

Comment: I have now uploaded updated code to Github, seems it's the rendering of the GUI that's causing the issue, but i can't workout how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end never got the performance to a satisfactory level using the DOM and html components. So i re-wrote the grid code to render all the cells using HTM5 Canvas and the performance is no longer an issue, in fact it now renders quite happily on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be the issue. By profiling we see:

[image]

You have bursts of work with a regular interval, each taking about 85ms which is very abnormal. Looking down the call-stack there is a `triggerTimer` and a subsequent `startTimer` function calls.

Looking at the source code for these:
https://github.com/gazzer82/fcc-game-of-life/blob/a4a000a6cafa5877a4a15e59cec5184076905cc4/src/containers/lower_buttons.jsx#L12.

You need to return from `startTimer` in the condition. Otherwise `triggerTimer` and `startTimer` will call each other as fast as they can over and over again, spawning new timeouts each time.

Before

```
  startTimer(){
    var that = this;
    if(this.props.controls.game === 'running'){
      this.props.stepState();
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.triggerTimer(), this.props.controls.speed);
  }

  triggerTimer(){
    this.startTimer();
  }
```

After

```
startTimer(){
  var that = this;
  if(this.props.controls.game === 'running'){
    this.props.stepState();
    // Return here
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.triggerTimer(), this.props.controls.speed);
}

triggerTimer(){
  this.startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Hi Red, thanks for the reply. But it think you've misunderstood what i am doing with those functions. It's basically a recurring function which calculates the next state for the cells. So every x milliseconds (this.props.controls.speed) it effectively calls itself. If the game is running at that point it triggers an update to the cells states. Either way it then sets a timeout for calling itself again. Basically it's a setInterval() done this way to allow the user to adjust the speed of the timer. Whereas if i place the return where you have it, then it will not continue to loop.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry about that! At least by profiling, it can be seen that the startTimer and subsequently all the calculations are taking >80ms to execute each time so the problem lies somewhere in the js calculations and not in page layout or composition. I'll try to fork this and start it up.

Comment: No worries at all, I very much appreciate you trying to help! I think the issues are probably in how I am calculating the state for each cell in the cells action creator.

Comment: These dispatches seem to be taking the bulk of the time. http://imgur.com/a/ph22k
The `newState` execution is a bit heavy but nothing compared to the dispatches. http://imgur.com/a/jUc3R. I think this could means that the bulk of the JS execution is due to how components react to the new state. If you print out each of the conditions in the cells `shouldComponentUpdate` is any of them always true ? That would cause all the cells to render each time there is a new state

Comment: Yes makes sense that those are taking the most time. That's basically the dispatch to generate the new state of the cells, and the notification that the generation is complete and to update the state. But yes you're correct, the last one is always true, let me do a refactor now and see if that improved things.

Comment: Ok, so after some testing it does seem to be the rendering that is causing the slow down, if i instigate a shouldComponentUpdate() that always returns no then the state is updated on time as expected, but as soon as i re-enable the GUI it grinds to a halt. Is there a different way i can approach the data bindings that would speed everything up. At the moment i am iterating an array of objects to create each cell in a container components, is there a better way of doing this?